# Vue.js: folder is missing when publish

Tags: vue.js

When I publish the project: `npm run build` a folder that I created with images is missing from the `dist` folder.
I created this folder inside the src folder.
assets folder is also missing.
Where is it?

Comment: Where did you create the folder?

Comment: @tony19: Inside the src folder

Answer (score 1):

If you just want some folders included verbatim, put them in the [`public` folder](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder).

> Any static assets placed in the `public` folder will simply be copied and not go through webpack. You need to reference them using absolute paths.

Things within `src` are only included if they're part of the bundle (ie they have been imported / required) and even then, any folder structure won't be preserved. Bundled items are typically renamed with a hash checksum and all put into a single folder like `js`, `css`, `images`, etc.